# How to integrate Outlook in ASP.Net Core MVC 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, outlook, office365

I'm working on an ASP.Net Core web application. I have a requirement in which i have to integrate Outlook in my application. Basically i want to able to create events from my app into Outlook, Office 365.

The event would include

- title
- start date
- end date
- attachment from 365 drive(doc, spreadsheet) or local drive

I have searched a lot on it, but couldn't find anything related to Asp.Net core.

Followed this article till now: [How to use Outllok APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/dotnet-tutorial) but this article is 
in MVC not in .Net core.

I was getting an error as shown in the image attached, which says:

> Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectOptions'

[image: Error]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Should be **pretty much** the same, except that you start with an ASP.NET Core Web Application template (Choosing API in the wizard and "change authentication" to "Work or School Account") set up your application from there. Rest from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/dotnet-tutorial#using-the-mail-api should be same, except that instead of Reading from ConfigurationManager you use ASP.NET Core's Options pattern https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.1. Microsoft.Graphi already does run on .NET Core so no issues there

Comment: @Tseng please see my edits

Comment: Like I said, you can't follow it 1:1, but when you create a ASP.NET Core WebApi template using Work or School accounts, it should give the authentication part with Azure/Office 365, which should allow you to skip most (if not all) authentication part of the linked tutorial

Comment: I have a project already, so it means i have to create a new with Work or School account? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/calendar-rest-operations#CreateEvents In this section i clicked on the first option (i.e a url), entered my personal account email and it showed me error to login in with Work or School account

Comment: You can also diff the new project with and without work & school account authentication, see the differences and take this over in your existing account (if you didn't had Office 365/Azure AD Authentication before). The usage of the graphi API should be same, independently if you run on ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Core MVC, with some minor changes (i.e. HttpContext not being static accessible class but property of controller or injected via `IHttpContextAccessor`, but I assume you know that if you are using ASPNET Core already)

Comment: This is my first assignment on ASP.NET Core MVC

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft Graph API to access your email/profile/attachment :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mail-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0

Of course outlook mail rest api is also available .No matter use which kind of api , you need to api's permissions for your application in Azure portal if using Azure AD V1.0 endpoint . If you are using Azure AD V2.0 endpoint ,  you can [dynamic consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison#incremental-and-dynamic-consent) permissions.

For the authentication part , you can use OpenID Connect middleware for sign in(default `Work or School Account` authentication template ) and use ADAL (Azure AD v1.0) or MSAL (Azure AD v2.0) to acquire token for relevant API :

[Differences between ADAL and MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/adal-to-msal)

In short : 
ADAL applications allow users to sign-in with their work and school account and need to be registered in the [Azure portal](http://%20https://portal.azure.com/), while applications that use the new (in-preview) MSAL allow users to sign-in with either their work and school accounts or their personal accounts and need to be registered in the [application registration portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/), unless they are Azure AD B2C applications.

Code sample:

Please click [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/Extensions/AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs#L63) for code sample using ADAL to acquire token .Click [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-connect-sample/blob/master/MicrosoftGraphAspNetCoreConnectSample/Extensions/AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs#L78) for code sample using MSAL to acquire token . Both code samples are in .NET Core , and after that you can get the access token to access Microsoft Graph API or Outlook Rest API .